# EJB JAX-RS @Context HttpServletRequest NullPointerException - Why?

Tags: dependency-injection, ejb, jax-rs, resteasy, apache-tomee

Consider the following service:

```
@Path("/")
@Stateless
public class SomethingService {

    @Context
    final HttpServletRequest request

    @POST
    @Path("post/something/")
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public String addSomething(@FormParam("something") final String something) {
        // access to request methods results in NullPointerException
    }
}
```

I get a `NullPointerException` when the method executes, though in the debugging perspective I noticed `request` wasn't really `null` but rather an instance of `org.apache.openejb.rest.ThreadLocalHttpServletRequest`. When I move the `@Context` injection to the method parameter level, everything works fine:

```
public String addSomething(@FormParam("something") final String something,
    @Context final HttpServletRequest request) { ... }
```

What is the reason for this? As far as I remember it used to work before I made the service an EJB (which I did to make injection of DAOs using `@EJB` or `@Inject` possible). Does JAX-RS create an instance of such a service for every request and hence is able to inject via class level `@Context`? Does EJB prevent this by creating the instance and filling in proxy objects before JAX-RS can do anything?

Answer (score 1):

necroing an old question -

When you turned this into stateless, it turned into a singleton model, so injecting fields is no longer thread safe.  The same thing happens when you turn a jax-rs service into Spring bean.    The safer way to do this is the workaround you mentioned, and inject the methods parameters.